# Simple method to delete files from Server

Tags: php, bash

I want to remove some files from my server after certain time intervals.
The File names follows pattern (i.e. temp1.jpg, temp2.jpg, temp3.jpg,.. so on).
I hosted my website on [www.000webhost.com](https://www.000webhost.com/). Apache 2.2.19 (Unix) is installed on 000webhost.com. How can I achieve this, using bash script. Or maybe by some simple method in php. 
Well I know intermediate Bash scripting and php. 
Appreciate for help.

Comment: Use filemtime and unlink in PHP.

Comment: "Unlink" should delete the file through php

Comment: rm *.jpg will work, but I want to delete these files after certain time intervals. Cause I don't want to do rm *.jpg after every 10 minutes

Comment: Any possiblility in Bash Script?

Comment: well about 10 minutes.

Comment: `exec("find yout/path/*.jpg -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;");` < jpgs over thats 30 days

Comment: `exec("find yout/path/*.jpg -mmin +10 -exec rm {} \;");` < jpgs over 10 minutes old

Comment: @Dagon, Well appreciate for help, you can add this as answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash\command line\cron script

`find yout/path/*.jpg  -type f -mmin +10 -exec rm {} \;`

for php just wrap in `exec`

edit: added `-type f` to be safer